# Serial monitor (arduino) through python code not working

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I wrote a code for a stepper motor connected to A4998 driver connected to arduino:

```
// defines pins numbers
const int stepPin = 3; 
const int dirPin = 4; 
const int cycle = 200*8;

void setup() {
  // Sets the two pins as Outputs
  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    
    char val = Serial.read();
    
    if (val == '1') {
      digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH); // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
      // Makes 200 pulses for making one full cycle rotation
      for(int i=0; i<=cycle/10; i++){
         digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
         delayMicroseconds(1000); 
         digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
         delayMicroseconds(1000);
        } 
      // delay(2000);
      }
    
    if (val == '0') {
      digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW); // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
      // Makes 200 pulses for making one full cycle rotation
      for(int i=0; i<=cycle/10; i++){
         digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
         delayMicroseconds(1000); 
         digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
         delayMicroseconds(1000);
        } 
      // delay(2000);
      }
  }
}
```

This is working well when i'm using the Serial Monitor in the arduino program,
but when i'm trying to start the motor from my python code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM8', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

ser.write(b'1')

ser.close()
```

It doesn't work, nothing happening.

What am i missing?

Thank You.

Comment: try putting a delay for a second or so right after creating the serial object ... in my experience something with the arduino seems to take some non-zero time to initialize